# Startview visible above endview in MaterialContainerTransform

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, floating-action-button, android-transitions

I'm learning transitions in Android with Material Motion. Following the documentation and the sample app, Reply, I have managed to implement a container transformation between a FAB and a new fragment. The thing is, the FAB is above the new fragment until the transition ends, resulting in the following visual bug.

Code for managing the transition:

```
enterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            startView = newRecipeBtn
            endView = binding.recipePager
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            duration = resources.getInteger(R.integer.motion_duration_large).toLong()
            startContainerColor = resources.getColor(R.color.secondaryColor)
            containerColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorSurface)
            endContainerColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorSurface)
        }
        returnTransition = Slide().apply {
            addTarget(R.id.recipe_pager)
            resources.getInteger(R.integer.motion_duration_large).toLong()
        }
```

[MaterialContainerTransition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLOLM.gif)

As you can see I have already change the colors for the start and end containers as the documentation suggest in case they have different background colors.
Hope someone can guide me in the right directions cause I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty but late I have figured out the solution.

### Reason

Lemme to the point, actually the thing was our 2nd fragment's background is `Color.TRANSPARENT` by default. In any kind of animation, just the view gets updated not the physical size. For example, if you have an animation to scale fab, fab won't get affected by scaling anim. Similar thing happening here.

### Clarification

I hope you followed [codeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-android#4), there they set `emailCarview` as `startView`. If you noticed entire `fragment_compose.xml` is covered with views with no space left for `Color.TRANSPARENT`. Thereby everything is fine there.

### How to fix

Just add `android:background="?attr/colorSurface"` on your 2nd fragment/activity. Don't worry about themes, it will be fine as normal.